# How would I integrate Dash apps into a single website hosted on a single server?

Tags: html, flask, server, plotly-dash

I am working on a project in which there are two existing sites, call them A and B. Currently, each site is a Dash app, and has to be hosted locally on separate ports to access each one. I am assigned the task of creating a home page that leads to the two sites, say with hyperlinks. All three pages should be hosted on the same server, and A and B should avoid having significant alterations to the code. Please note that I am not too familiar with web development, so if explanations could be simple that would be great.

Currently, I have two paths that I think are possible.

1. The home page is a Dash app. It imports the Dash python files of A and B, and renders them when the suffix to the base url changes. E.g.

```
from pages import A

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])

@callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
          Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return "homepage"
    elif pathname == '/page1':
        return A.app.layout
    else:
        return '404'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port='5510', debug=True)
```

The odd thing is that the layout of A when accessed in this way is different compared to when A is directly hosted on its own server. I am doing it this way instead of using Dash Pages, since for legacy reasons, A and B can only use older versions of Dash.

2. I already have a home page made using an html template, so I use a Flask app hosted on its own server to render the html page as the home page, and A and B as necessary, depending on the url suffix as before. I am not quite sure how to do this - I am trying to follow this [article](https://medium.com/@olegkomarov_77860/how-to-embed-a-dash-app-into-an-existing-flask-app-ea05d7a2210b), but I don't understand it.

If there is advice on how to implement either of these ways, or suggestions for better alternatives to these methods, that would be greatly appreciated.